# Using TOAD data modeler with existing TOAD Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, data-modeling, toad

I need to start a long-term project in mapping out data tables so that we can get a high-level view of what information we store in our Oracle database and how the tables are linked to each other. This is largely for GDPR preparation.

Since our organization has been around for a number of decades, its database is massive. With TOAD for Oracle, I'm able to see all columns in our tables easily, so I started looking at different database mapping tools (ER/ONE, DDM, Astah) but they all look like I need to manually create all the tables and columns and draw their relationships out by hand.

I'm hoping to minimize as much manual labor as possible and am wondering if using TOAD data modeler would help since I'm using TOAD for Oracle anyways. **Could I somehow automate the table, column, and relationship creation process?**

Our organization only has Oracle's base version unfortunately (I think the premium bundle has data mapper included in it maybe... not sure.) Any thoughts on the options I have?

-

Bundle: Toad for Oracle Base (64-bit), Add-Ons: <-none->

Comment: Does your database have the primary/foreign key actually defined in the table definitions or are they just assumed based on a column name or similar?

Comment: I checked the scripts and only saw primary keys being defined. Was not able to find foreign keys for some reason. I'll have to ask the DBAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our organization only has Oracle's base version

Note: TOAD is not an Oracle product, it is [owned and developed by Quest](https://www.quest.com/).

> they all look like I need to manually create all the tables and columns and draw their relationships out by hand

Any decent data modelling tool supports reverse engineer a physical data model from an existing schema. How good the derived model is will depend on how good your schema is (my bet: decades of development without an existing data modelling tool? not good). For instance, if your schema has foreign keys the reverse engineering process will use them to draw the relationships between tables (even if they are disabled). But if there are no foreign keys then you're on your own.

As you're using already TOAD you are right to want the TOAD modelling extension. You can buy it as a standalone purchase. But if your company won't spring for the extra licenses you should check out Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler. It's free and it has the most comprehensive support for idiomatic Oracle. (I'm not saying it's the best DM tool of them all but it's very good for something which is free). [Find out more](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll test out the free version and its reverse engineering capabilities before looking into TOAD data modeler.